# Asterisk Pyramid in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Exercise: make a program that reads a natural number *n* and draws a pyramid of asterisks. Model for `n = 5`:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Code:

```c
int main ()
{
    int n, i, j=1, aux1, aux2;
    int spaces=1;
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        spaces += 1;
    }
    printf ("\n");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        aux1 = j;
        aux2 = spaces;

        while (aux2 >= 1)
        {
            printf (" ");
            aux2--;
        }

        while (aux1 >= 1)
        {
            printf ("*");
            aux1--;
        }

        j += 2;
        spaces--;

        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My code is receiving "Presentation Error" from online judge because the last asterisks of every line have a space after. 
Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: Print one less space at the end of each line?

Comment: Have you verified that it actually *is* including a space after?

Comment: Yes, Scott Hunter.

Comment: With your code, I cannot understand why there is a space at the end of each line. But at the beginning of each line, there are 2 separate spaces.

Comment: When you mean a new line, just add an `\n` to your `printf("\n\n");`

Comment: Note that your loop `for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        spaces += 1;
    }` is a funny way of writing `spaces = n + 1;`, given that `spaces` is initialized to `1`, and it's quite slow, too.  If it's any consolation, I came across an equivalent loop in one of the bits of code I work on just last week — I was duly staggered and (after checking with a colleague that I wasn't just imagining it) made the relevant change there, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has spaces at the start of each line, not the end.

Here is the simplest way I can think of to go about solving that problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int i, j, height;

    scanf("%d", &height);

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < height - i - 1; j++)
            putchar(' ');

        for (; j < height + i; j++)
            putchar('*');

        putchar('\n');
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "Presentation Error" yet. :(

Comment: Uh, this one *intentionally* adds spaces at the end of each line - why?  Also, is the OP actually reading the code?

Comment: @gmn_1450 I added extra spaces at the end so that the output would be "block-ish", but it was a mistake. Should work correctly now.

Comment: @SteveFriedl For some reason I assumed the each "line" had to have the same size and so I evened them out by adding spaces at the end. It's fixed now, thank you for the correction!

Comment: I get it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's *not* including a space after the asterisks, and it's easy enough to see this for yourself.  Near the bottom where you included the newline after the stars, I added an endmarker (`|`) just so we can see: is there a space?

I don't see one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n;
    scanf ("%d", &n);

    int spaces_before_stars = n - 1;

    printf ("\n");

    int i, nstars;

    for (i = 0, nstars = 1; i<n; i++)
    {
        int aux1 = nstars;
        int aux2 = spaces_before_stars;

        while (aux2-- > 0)
            printf (" ");

        while (aux1-- > 0)
            printf("*");

        nstars += 2; 

        spaces_before_stars--;

        printf ("|\n");    // the "|" marks the end of the line, remove for final
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**However** your version of the code had spaces at the *start* of each line, which is probably what the presentation code is unhappy with.

Refactoring the code a bit with better variable names makes it easier to follow - you should see no extra leading spaces and no trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Given n>0, this should do the trick, assuming alternating blank lines is desired and a trailing extraneous new line allowed.

```
char *ast = malloc(n * 2);
if (ast == NULL)
   return(1);
memset(ast, '*', n*2);
ast[(n*2)-1] = 0;
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
   int spaces = n - i;
   printf("%*s%.*s\n\n", spaces, "", (i*2)-1, ast);
}
free(ast);
return (0);
```

Comment: This looks too clever by half: if the OP is having problems w/ basic loop control, decoding magic `printf` formats is not going to be an easy lift.

Comment: @SteveFriedl Perhaps

Comment: I consider this "better" printf formatting:
`int main(void) {
 int n = 5;
 char stars[2*n];
 memset(stars, '*', 2*n);
 for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
 {
  printf("%*.*s\n",n+i,2*i+1,stars);
 }
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @abelenky I agree. It's easier to comprehend.