# Number Pyramid in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Exercise: Make a program that reads a natural number *n* less than 100 and draws pyramids of the example output formats, each with *n* lines Output for *n* = 11:

```
01
02 02
03 03 03
04 04 04 04
05 05 05 05 05
06 06 06 06 06 06 
07 07 07 07 07 07 07
08 08 08 08 08 08 08 08 
09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 09 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

```
01
01 02
01 02 03
01 02 03 04
01 02 03 04 05
01 02 03 04 05 06
01 02 03 04 05 06 07
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11
```

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j,n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(i + 1 < 10)
                printf("0%d ", i+1);
            else if(i + 1 >= 10)
                printf("%d ", i+1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if(j + 1 < 10)
                printf("0%d ", j+1);
            else if(j + 1 >= 10)
                printf("%d ", j+1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code is receiving "Presentation Error" from online judge, probably because the last numbers of every line have a space after.

Any tips on how to fix it?

I know I've posted a similar question, but I don't think I understood the solution completely.

Comment: Ok, it's important that you actually understand the code. Can you determine even generally where this extra space might be coming from?

Comment: I second Steve's remark. Per the SO homework policy, [never turn in code you don't understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: @mamounothman that's not going to do what you think it does.

Comment: FYI, other question is here, and it's not clear the OP understands the code, so this is not really helping them much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59709181/asterisk-pyramid-in-c/59709310

Comment: It's basically the same fundamental question, so I hope OP wil be picking up the technique soon. I'm voting to close as too broad because I don't really see an honest effort here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much shorter version to print both pyramids:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pyramid1(int n)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
            printf("%s%02d", j? " " : "", i);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void pyramid2(int n)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
        for(int j=1; j<=i; ++j)
            printf("%s%02d", j>1? " " : "", j);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(void) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    pyramid1(n);
    printf("\n\n");
    pyramid2(n);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

*(for n==5)*

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4336KB
01
02 02
03 03 03
04 04 04 04
05 05 05 05 05


01
01 02
01 02 03
01 02 03 04
01 02 03 04 05
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid the trailing blanks is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        printf("%s%.2d", pad, i+1);
        pad = " ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

For the first number in the line, `pad` is empty, so the number alone is output.  For all the subsequent ones, `pad` is a single blank; you get a blank output before the new number.

I find minor variations on this technique very useful.  For example, you could use `pad = "Data: ";` and then `pad = ", "` to generate a comma-separated list of values:

```
Data: 01, 02, 03
```

<sup>(I've not reviewed whether the loop limits (`i < n`, `j <= i`) are correct; that's a separate discussion.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution for both types of the pyramide

```
void pyr(int n, int type)
{
    for(int row = 1; row <= n; row++)
        for(int col = 1; col <= row; col++)
            printf("%02d%c", type ? col : row , col == row ? '\n' : ' ');
}


int main()
{
    pyr(11,0);
    pyr(11,1);
}
```

You can play it yourself here: https://godbolt.org/z/oPv84T

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the space as a postfix on every iteration, use the space as a prefix on every iteration by the first.

Instead of this:

```
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if(i + 1 < 10)
            printf("0%d ", i+1);
        else if(i + 1 >= 10)
            printf("%d ", i+1);
    }
```

Apply a slight change of using a leading space:

```
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (j != 0)
            printf(" "); // print the leading space

        if(i + 1 < 10)
            printf("0%d", i+1);
        else if(i + 1 >= 10)
            printf("%d", i+1);
    }
```

And if you want to look clever:

```
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        int val = i+1;
        const char* prefix1 = (j==0) ? "" : " ";
        printf("%s%02d", prefix1, val);
    }
```

Comment: The if/else test could be combined to `printf("%02d", i+1);`

Comment: Or `printf("%.2d", i+1);`